# Is there a standard monad for the "opposite" of the maybe monad?

Tags: f#, monads

The maybe monad allows to chain a set of operators that all may fail (by returning None), and at the end returns `Some result` if every suboperation succeeded, or `None` if anything failed. Here's a small dummy example:

```
type MaybeBuilder() =
    member this.Return(x) = 
        Some x
    member this.Bind(m, f) = 
        match m with
        | Some x -> f x
        | None -> None

let maybe = MaybeBuilder()

let list = [1;2;3;4]

// evaluates to Some 3
maybe {
    let! x1 = List.tryFind ((=) 1) list
    let! x2 = List.tryFind ((=) 2) list
    return x1 + x2
}

// evaluates to None 
maybe {
    let! x1 = List.tryFind ((=) 1) list
    let! x2 = List.tryFind ((=) 6) list
    return x1 + x2
}
```

This is roughly equivalent to this:

```
// evaluates to Some 3
match List.tryFind ((=) 1) list with
| None -> None
| Some x1 ->
    match List.tryFind ((=) 2) list with
    | None -> None
    | Some x2 -> Some (x1 + x2)

// evaluates to None
match List.tryFind ((=) 1) list with
| None -> None
| Some x1 ->
    match List.tryFind ((=) 6) list with
    | None -> None
    | Some x2 -> Some (x1 + x2)
```

In a piece of code I have I'm currently doing the "opposite" of this, returning the first successfull hit:

```
// evaluates to Some 1
match List.tryFind ((=) 1) list with
| Some x1 -> Some x1
| None ->
    match List.tryFind ((=) 2) list with
    | Some x2 -> Some x2
    | None -> None

// evaluates to Some 2
match List.tryFind ((=) 6) list with
| Some x1 -> Some x1
| None ->
    match List.tryFind ((=) 2) list with
    | Some x2 -> Some x2
    | None -> None
```

Is this also possible to do with a monad to get the nice computation expression syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some time ago, I wrote a blog that implements [imperative computation builder in F#](http://tomasp.net/blog/imperative-i-return.aspx/).  For example, the following is a computation that returns 0 and never executes the `printfn` statement:

```
let test() = imperative {
  return 0
  printfn "after return!"
  return 1 }
```

I think your code sample could be written as:

```
imperative { return! List.tryFind ((=) 1) list 
             return! List.tryFind ((=) 2) list }
```

#### How does it work?

As you suggest (and Lee mentioned too), the type is also based on the `option<'T>` type, with the minor difference that I'm using a delayed option value (so that you can compose computations without evaluating them), so the type of the monadic type is actually:

```
type Imperative<'T> = unit -> option<'T>
```

The key trick in the computation builder is to add `Combine` (which behaves like `mplus` in Lee's Haskell version) that runs the first computation and returns its result (if it was `Some`) or runs the rest (if it was `None`) (both `a` and `b` are actually functions here - so we need to call them & delay the result):

```
member x.Combine(a, b) = (fun () ->
  match a() with 
  | Some(v) -> Some(v) // if it returned, we can return the result immediately
  | _ -> b() )         // otherwise, we need to run the second part
```

It actually works really nicely - you can add support for loops & exception handling and if you make the type more complicated you can add other features like `break`:

```
imperative { 
  for x in 1 .. 5 do 
    if (x % 2 = 0) then do! continue
    printfn "number = %d" x }
```

Answer (score 6):

Tomas' solution with

```
imperative { 
    return! List.tryFind ((=) 1) list
    return! List.tryFind ((=) 2) list }
```

does what I wanted, but I just realised that I could also achieve what I needed more simply with just this:

```
// evaluates to Some 1
[1;2] |> List.tryPick (fun x -> List.tryFind ((=) x) list)
// evaluates to Some 2
[6;2] |> List.tryPick (fun x -> List.tryFind ((=) x) list)
```

Comment: +1 It's easy to overlook simple solutions when one has a big hammer!

Answer (score 5):

Haskell does this with the `MonadPlus` type class defined as:

```
class Monad m => MonadPlus m where
  mzero :: m a
  mplus :: m a -> m a -> m a
```

`Maybe` implements this type class as

```
instance MonadPlus Maybe where
  mzero                   = Nothing
  Nothing `mplus` Nothing = Nothing
  Just x  `mplus` Nothing = Just x
  Nothing `mplus` Just x  = Just x
  Just x  `mplus` Just y  = Just x
```

It appears that the `mzero` and `mplus` members of `MonadPlus` correspond to the `Zero` and `Combine` members used by F# computation expressions.

Comment: Yes, `mzero` and `mplus` correspond to `Zero` and `Combine` :-) but to make it behave reasonably, you also need to add `Delay` (because F# is not lazy) and it is a good idea to add `For`/`While`/`TryWith`/etc. to support standard language constructs in the computation block...

Answer (score 4):

You could also define a simple function to do this:

```
let orElse f = function
  | None -> f()
  | Some _ as x -> x
```

You could chain together as many functions as you like, with the first `Some` result being returned as the result of the entire expression:

```
List.tryFind ((=) 1) list
|> orElse (fun () -> List.tryFind ((=) 2) list)
|> orElse (fun () -> List.tryFind ((=) 3) list)
|> orElse (fun () -> List.tryFind ((=) 4) list)
```

Comment: this is also a nice solution

Answer (score 1):

This special case can be also emulated with sequences:

```
let tests = seq {
  yield List.tryFind ((=) 5) list
  yield List.tryFind ((=) 3) list
  yield List.tryFind ((=) 6) list
}

tests |> Seq.tryFind Option.isSome |> Option.bind id
```